# Block all files from being accessed directly via htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

A security audit highlighted an issue where some files could be accessed directly eg www.domain.com/readme.txt

No biggy as there is nothing on the server that contains anything sensitive although this isn't going to cut it on the audit and we need to patch this.

Is there a way to block ALL files from being accessed directly unless though the website or specified (file extension)? Hoping it can be achieved via htaccess?

Comment: put file outside web root

Comment: Not practical in this scenario :(

Comment: there are a dozen dupes, but just go with the answer below

Comment: if you need the file to be viewable in a browser (e.g. images), then there's no way to protect them. it is impossible to 100% reliably differentiate between "nasty person directly accessing file" v.s. "nice normal user accessing file to view in web page". if you don't want something viewable over the web, then don't make it available over the web - keep it outside the site's document root.

Answer (score 0):

```
order allow,deny
<Files ~ ".(php|html|js|css)$">
   allow from all
</Files>
```

(Php, html, js and css are allowed to access)

Comment: excellent - does this need to go in all directories or is just putting in the root sufficient?

Comment: This works on my machine but shows the Linux default page on others after I upload it? any ideas?